# AC: Black Flag multiplayer functional?

Tags: assassins-creed-4-black-flag

I have recently seen this game on sale and I'm wondering - is the multiplayer part still available? By available I mean:

- servers are still working
- it is possible to find (or make) a game within an acceptable amount of time
- (bonus) is it possible to create two-player games?

I know it's quite many years after the original release of this game, but maybe Ubisoft hasn't shut down the multiplayer part of this game?

Can anyone owning the game actually confirm it still works?

Edit: Forgot to mention - I'm playing on PC.

Comment: I know the servers were still up but a few months ago and I managed to find a game within 3-5 minutes. I can't verify right now though as I've uninstalled my game since then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes the servers are still functional, though it may not necessary seem like it because no one is ever on. Though many people still play AC4 Black Flag I just don't think anyone bothers with the multiplayer. Hope that helped! :D

Comment: That suits my needs, as I mainly wanted to play with my friend. Thanks!